# Flutter SharedPreferences Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, flutter-sharedpreference

I've made a class for shared preferences. The class is as follows

```
class StorageUtil {
  static StorageUtil? _storageInstance;
  static SharedPreferences? _preferences;

  static Future<StorageUtil?> getInstance() async {
    if (_storageInstance == null) {
      _storageInstance = StorageUtil();
    }
    if (_preferences == null) {
      _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
    return _storageInstance;
  }

  addStringtoSF(String key, String value) async {
    print(' inside sharedPreferences file $key $value'); // Receives data here
    await _preferences!.setString(key,
        value); //Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
  }
```

When ever i try to store the values i'm getting a error 'Null check operator used on a null value'

This is how i'm passing down the values to the store function. I'm receiving the data inside the function. But cannot store the values inside it. What causes this?

```
String? userResponse = json.encode(authResponse);
      print('This is userResponse type');
      _storageUtil.addStringtoSF('userData', userResponse);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`
in the very `first line of you main()` method in `main.dart` file if not present.

The problem over here is that

1. The class has a static function that is responsible for the initialization of variables and `can be accessed without an object of class StorageUtil`.
2. When the `nonstatic function` is called you `need to create an object of StorageUtil class` and then access that function due to which the `static variables are not initialized which are initialized in the static function hence null`.

From the snippet of code it seems you are willing to make a singleton class here is the correct code for it:

```
class StorageUtil {
  static StorageUtil storageInstance = StorageUtil._instance();
  static SharedPreferences? _preferences;

  StorageUtil._instance(){
    getPreferences();
  }
  void getPreferences()async{
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }


  addStringtoSF(String key, String value) async {
    print(' inside sharedPreferences file $key $value'); // Receives data here
    await _preferences!.setString(key,
        value);
  }
}
```

Where ever you want the preference to be used just call:

```
final StorageUtil storage = StorageUtil.storageInstance;
storage.AnyNonStaticFunctionName()// call for methods in the StorageUtil Class
```

this is the one and only object that will exist throughout the application.

Or

if you don't want to change your class then just add this in all the `nonstatic functions` at the top which uses `_preferences`

And also add this null check

```
if (_preferences == null) {
    _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

because you may be having multiple instances of the `StorageUtil` making the `_preferences` variable null each time.

Comment: But I'm already making a null check inside getInstancefuction

Comment: you are making it inside the getInstanceFunction but your function is static hence its not storing the _preference it it

Comment: for the next call on the other function

Answer (score 0):

Add this line also under your print line, before calling `_preferences!.`

```
if (_preferences == null) {
      _preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    }
```

Comment: But I'm already making a null check inside getInstancefuction

Comment: You're not calling it though. Just try it.